# Not able to convert DynamicFrame.toDF() getting exception

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I am trying to convert my DynamicFrame to DataFrame in AWS Glue ETL job. I am getting the exception below. Please note that my DynamicFrame has DynamicRecords with different columns per record. But my understanding was DynamicFrame handles those and generates DataFrame.

```
'An error occurred while calling o80.showString.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 619, ip-172-31-7-160.ec2.internal, executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.schema.types.StructType.fieldIndex(StructType.java:53)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(RecordToRow.scala:93)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(RecordToRow.scala:92)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)\n\tat scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$.convertField(RecordToRow.scala:92)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$.apply(RecordToRow.scala:43)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicRecord.toRow(DynamicRecord.scala:260)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame$$anonfun$toDF$1.apply(DynamicFrame.scala:280)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame$$anonfun$toDF$1.apply(DynamicFrame.scala:280)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:235)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)\n\tat org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n\nDriver stacktrace:\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)\n\tat scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.schema.types.StructType.fieldIndex(StructType.java:53)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(RecordToRow.scala:93)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(RecordToRow.scala:92)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)\n\tat scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$.convertField(RecordToRow.scala:92)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.RecordToRow$.apply(RecordToRow.scala:43)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicRecord.toRow(DynamicRecord.scala:260)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame$$anonfun$toDF$1.apply(DynamicFrame.scala:280)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame$$anonfun$toDF$1.apply(DynamicFrame.scala:280)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:235)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)\n\tat org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\t... 1 more\n')
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code which results in error?

Comment: Hi @AlexSkorokhod, Thanks for the response. Actually I found the problem, i had problem with my schema preparation.

Comment: @HarishG. What was the problem with your schema? I'm getting the same error and I do suspect it's the schema, but I'm not sure what about it Glue doesn't like.

Comment: Hi @GlennMoss, my input JSON had circular reference. To fix I mapped fields which I required to process.